"./firestore/" specifier in "@angular/fire" package

the err msg : An unhandled exception occurred: Missing ./firestore/ specifier in @angular/fire package
i tried to install versions of angular/fire  and unintall versions to fix this problem and i tried to change the path to the compa path but the problem is still the same ..

have you tried to reinstall @angular/fire ?

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.
